# How do I discover which messages a delegate can / should implement?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates

In Objective-C / Cocoa how do I discover the messages I can implement in a delegate class?

From what I have read in the documentation a class will only allow certain chosen messages to be handled via a delegate but so far have found difficulty finding a list of messages for a class.

To ask the question another way, if I created a delegate for NSApplication, which messages are available for me to handle?

The documentation for NSApplication states a delegate

> responds to certain messages on behalf of NSApp.

The documentation then goes onto say

> NSApplication defines over twenty delegate methods that offer opportunities for modifying specific aspects of application behavior.

but as far as I can see it fails to list these methods / messages so how do I know which ones will be called from my delegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delegate is usually supposed to conform to a protocol declared for that purpose, e.g. [NSApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). If it's not clearly spelled out already, you can often find the name of the appropriate protocol by looking at the type of the `delegate` property (in this case, [`id<NSApplicationDelegate>`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/delegate)). You can check the documentation for details on the methods, or the @protocol declaration in the appropriate header file for specifics on which methods are available and which are required or optional.

There are some cases where the object does not define a protocol for its delegate, for example [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html). In this case, you just have to follow the documentation of the class with respect to what it expects of its delegate.

In either case, it is completely up to the class when it sends a message to the delegate and what the semantics of any message are.

Comment: So if the class documentation is sparse on information regarding the delegate I should do a search for <classname>delegate E.G. if i wanted to know about which messages a window delegate can implement I would search for NSWindowDelegate?

Comment: @Benjamin: That is the usual naming convention. A more straightforward way is to check the type of the `delegate` property, as it will most often be along the lines of `id<FooDelegate>` (meaning "any object that conforms to the FooDelegate protocol").

Answer (score 1):

These methods are described in the `NSApplicationDelegate` documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

One quick note that is that it is useful to understand the difference between formal and informal protocols. Also formal protocols have optional methods, which needn't be called.
When you write your own protocol you will want to check -respondsToSelector: before sending optional/informal methods.

formal protocols are defined like...

```
@protocol SomeProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)someMethod:(id)sender;
-(void)someOtherMethod:(NSString*)aString;
@property(nonatomic,retain) someProperty;

@optional
-(BOOL)someOptionalMethod;

@end
```

and are adopted like...

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject <SomeProtocol> {

}
@end
```

this tells the compiler that you are adopting SomeProtocol, and you wont be required to declare you methods for the protocol in the .h file, it also tell the compiler to warn you if you haven't implemented all of the required methods.

for informal protocols you don't adopt them syntactically, but you will need to declare your methods in the .h file.

Comment: +1 for the extra information even though the question has already been closed. Thank you.